# Returnn Switchboard data processing

Tags: returnn

Could anybody give me pointers on how to process Switchboard dataset for training with RETURNN? I did see BlissDataset class that seems to be designed for switchboard, but it's not clear to me what I should include in the paths given in the example:

```
Example:
    ./tools/dump-dataset.py "
      {'class':'BlissDataset',
       'path': '/u/tuske/work/ASR/switchboard/corpus/xml/train.corpus.gz',
       'bpe_file': '/u/zeyer/setups/switchboard/subwords/swb-bpe-codes',
       'vocab_file': '/u/zeyer/setups/switchboard/subwords/swb-vocab'}"
```

The switchboard dataset has several folders with audios, i.e. swb1_d2/data/*.sph and transcripts swb1_LDC97S62/swb_ms98_transcriptions/**/*
I'm not quite sure how to proceed with this to get a dataset that can be used to train RETURNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At our group (RWTH Aachen University), we use the config as it was published on GitHub. As you see, this one uses `ExternSprintDataset`. That dataset uses 
The implementation uses Sprint (publicly called RWTH ASR (RASR), see [here](https://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/rwth-asr/)) as an external tool (ran in a subprocess) to handle the data (feature extraction, etc). Sprint gets a Bliss XML file which describes all the segments with path to audio and audio offsets and transcriptions, and also it gets further configs for the feature extraction and maybe other things. There is an open source version of RASR which should work but it might be a bit involved to get this to work.

The `BlissDataset` was planned to be a simpler replacement for that. However, the implementation is incomplete. Also, you still would need to generate the Bliss XML by yourself in some way (we have used some own internal scripts to prepare that based on the official LDC data).

So, unfortunately, there is no simple way yet. Actually, I think the easiest way would be to come up with yet another custom format, which might be similar to the `LibriSpeechDataset` implementation, or maybe just the same, and then you could just reuse `LibriSpeechDataset`, or at least parts of that. That dataset implementation takes the data in some zip format which contains the transcripts in txt files and the audio in ogg or wav files. It uses librosa to do MFCC feature extraction (or also other feature types). I planned to implement that for Switchboard, and then reproduce the results, however I did not have time yet and not sure when I will get to that. But if you want to try that on your own, I will be happy to help you however I can. The starting point would be to look at `LibriSpeechDataset` and understand how the format of that looks like.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the state of things, I will try to replicate LibriSpeechDataset.